# HTML date input setting what arrows control by default

Tags: html, date, input

Is there any way of telling a date input

```
<input type="date" />
```

which field should be controlled by the arrows on the right by default?
They are setting the year but I'd like to set them so they control the day by default. (I know I could click on the day field, but that's what I'm trying to avoid!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer!
One of my friends realized that it always changes the first field, and the contents of the first field is affected by the computers date/time display settings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is - at least not with HTML alone. The `date` input type is at the moment not supported that widely, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime.

For me, on Chrome, it manipulates the day by default.

You may want to check out [jQuery Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).